# Import .CSV files onto SQLite

Tags: sqlite, import

I am having some problem in importing a .csv file into a sqlite table. My .csv file looks like this

```
Name,Age,,
Hamish,27,,
Praveen,27,,
```

There are no trailing spaces anywhere. I create a table in the SQLite db with the same schema, but when i run `.import`...it shows me an error saying "expected 2 columns of data but found 1". Probably something to do with the delimiter. Any ideas?

Comment: Check http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles to see if you have formatted your CSV correctly.

Comment: Hello Thanks for this info. I verified this info and it would appear that my csv file is fine. What i have is a No, space,No tab flat text file with three lines, One heading and two records...simply put like this Name,Age,, followed by two lines of records in the similar pattern :( Any ideas???

Comment: @Ivo your link is dead now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you specify the delimiter, and do so without quotes:

```
.separator ,
```